# How do you make buildozer install a kivy application on an android device without deleting the previous one?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to install a kivy application on my android device without deleting the previously installed one. Please would I be able to do this with buildozer?

Comment: Try just changing the `title` property in your `buildozer.spec`.

Comment: it still didn't work. It removed the previously installed one.

Comment: It's the name and/or identifier you would need to change, not the title. However, this functionally makes it a different app. Is this an XY problem, do you actually want to install a new version of the app but simply not overwrite everything from the previous one?

Comment: The `title` in the `spec` file becomes the name of the app. Probably also need to chaange the 'package.name'.

Comment: Changing the package name actually worked, thank you very much.